# Java: memory efficient storing of arrays of integers

Tags: java, arrays, list, hash

**Premise**: This problem might be already known, and I might be using the wrong wording, please refer me elsewhere if this is the case.

**Quick Problem Overview**: I have to store a high number of arrays of integers in order to avoid duplication. I am doing the following:

```
LinkedList<int[]> ArraysAlreadyUsed;
```

Upon using an array, I add it to the list. Before using an array I see if it is in the list. Since I need to use many high dimensional arrays I run into memory issues.

**Question**: What is a good/the best way of doing this in order to minimize the amount of memory occupied?
Is there a way to represent such arrays with a hash string? And would this be better?

Comment: LinkedList is a poor choice both in terms of memory overhead and iteration. Use ArrayList instead. However, an exhaustive linear search for an array seems like a bad idea to begin with.

Comment: I wasnt able to understand your problem clearly, but seems like you can solve your problem if you give your throughts on using hashmap to your situation

Comment: @rave763 How would I use hashmap in this case? what would I map my arrays of integer to?

Comment: Let me know if my understand of your situation is right , have a few arrays with various numbers ie [1,2,3] , [2,3,4] , [1,2,3]. You want a solution to whether at a given time you have already processed thaat array .. i.e in above scenario u have already used [1,2,3] so you wouldnt process it again

Comment: ok cool : I dnt knw whether it is the best solution in the world.. But here is how i would have done it. I would have first designed an algorithm to generate the key. Example myAlgorithm add the values in the array. so my hashmap entries will be (6,[1,2,3]) , (9, [2,3,4]) now when the third array is reached i will do a get(6). it will retrive me an array and then i will make a check if my array matches to the one in the hashmap. although is suggest ur key generation algorith should be very effiecent to avoid large key collosion... Happy coding

Comment: When you mention 'memory issues' I assume you're running out of memory. The first fix is to see if you can allocate more memory to the JVM using the -Xmx=???m parameter. If you're allocating massive numbers of very large arrays you could get into fragmentation issue where the JVM can't allocate a requested contiguous block of memory. If you can't configure your way out that corner you may need to consider a different data structure such as some kind of 'chunked' array implemented as one or more extents of (say) 10000 elements.

Comment: @rave763. Right principle but just summing the elements will typically prove to be a poor hash. Arrays that are permutations of each other will have the same hash and in most applications the elements are selected from a biased distribution that means such circumstances are more common than random chance. If you dig into the hash suggested by Assliyas below you'll a hash that is not much more expensive to compute but generally found to perform well for real world problems. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#hashCode(int[])

Answer (score 2):

It may make sense to create a wrapper that implements `equals` and `hashcode` so that you can place the arrays in a `Set` for O(1) `contains`/`add`. Something like:

```
public class IntArray {
  private final int[] array;
  private final int hash;

  public IntArray(int[] array) {
    this.array = array;
    this.hash = Arrays.hashCode(this.array); //cache hashcode for better performance
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return hash;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null) return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) return false;
    final IntArray other = (IntArray) obj;
    return Arrays.equals(this.array, other.array);
  }
}
```

You can then simply use a set:

```
Set<IntArray> arrays = new HashSet<> ();
```

That will create a small overhead (guestimate less than 20 bytes per wrapper) but will perform much better than your LinkedList.

If memory is your only concern then you could go for an `int[][]` but that will be more painful...

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check the presence of an element in a data structure the best solution is to use a `Map`. So use an `HashMap`.

Retrieve of elements happens in **O(1)**. In a list (`LinkedList` or `ArrayList`) the search happens in **O(n)**.

A linked list is also a poor choice in term of memory occupation. Infact for each element you have a reference to the previous element and a reference to the next element.

Just in term of memory occupations the best solution is using an array of int (not an `ArrayList`) with a reference to the last inserted id.

Answer (score 0):

Using a [BitSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) in place of `int[]` might reduce the memory footprint.